# Delete Column in CSV when element is certain value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am parsing a large amount of data so I need to delete a column in CSV. I would like to delete a column if it contains 0 and 32800.

There is no header too.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean before importing it into Python?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: well noted thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a column with a specific value, you can try doing this:

```
data.loc[:, ~(data == 0).any()]
```

or this

```
data.drop(columns=data.columns[(data == 0).any()])
```

- `(data == 0)` alone gives you a dataframe with booleans (whether 0 appears in df or not)
- `(data == 0).any()` tells you if there is any 0's in the columns of df
- So when you do this `data.columns[(data == 0).any()]` it tells you that in data there are 0 values in one or some columns.

Comment: can you please help explain [(df == 0).any()]?

Comment: i think i know the issue, the data frame types are strings. Hence nothing is deleted.

Comment: You mean the values in columns ? If this concerns you can change the type from strings to integer or float by doing data['column'].astype(float). Otherwise, you can just replace ```0``` by ```'0'```.

Comment: just now i replaced 0 with '0' and the boolean values are correct. but still did not delete rows

Comment: `circe_parsed_df.drop(columns=circe_parsed_df.columns[(circe_parsed_df == '0').any()])`

Comment: sorry to keep bothering but I am new to phyton

Comment: Your question was about deleting columns, not rows, so the code you're running is deleting columns that contain 0 and NOT rows.

Comment: i am trying to delete the columns but the result of the code i given is still the same. Nothing is deleted in the dataframe.

Comment: Well, you need take into consideration the modifications. So you have to assign the dataframe its new value : ```circe_parsed_df = circe_parsed_df.drop(columns=circe_parsed_df.columns[(circe_parsed_df == '0').any()]```

Comment: i did that too. nothing is deleted still.

Comment: perhaps i have a typo earlier. its working now thank you so much!